# How do I tell Postgres to convert existing values to new values?

Tags: postgresql

### ***Problem***

I have a table that has `parent_id` and `child_id`, and they are mutually exclusive, so naturally they should be just one value, not two. I need to replace them with `external_id`.

So any child id's will now become external ids, and any parent id's will also become external id's.

*How can I get postgres to convert the ids to the new column?*

### ***Messy, Potential Solution***

The only thing that comes to mind is to perform this in a few, very messy steps, but I'm hoping there's a better way:

1. CREATEa new column, `external_ids`.
2. Print all child and parent ids, even if they are null into a series of UPDATE strings, such as

   ```
   UPDATE table SET external_id = "<parent or child id>" WHERE row_id = <row_id>
   ```
3. Run each Update string individually, and that seems like it could take a really long time, so that's why I'm thinking there's gotta be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the coalesce function.

```
 UPDATE table SET external_id = coalesce( parent_id, child_id);
```